# Image not rendering in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following JavaScript code, that when called should render an image and a subtitle into an HTML5 canvas:

```
var SplashScreen = function SplashScreen(imagePath, subtitle, callback) {
    var up = false;
    this.step = function (dt) {
        if (!Game.keys['fire']) up = true;
        if (up && Game.keys['fire'] && callback) callback();
    };

    this.draw = function (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";

        splashImage = new Image();
        splashImage.src = imagePath;
        splashImage.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(splashImage, Game.width / 2 - 420 / 2, Game.height / 2 - 100, 420, 263);
        }

        ctx.font = "bold 20px 'SF Collegiate'";
        var measure2 = ctx.measureText(subtitle);
        ctx.fillText(subtitle, Game.width / 2 - measure2.width / 2, Game.height / 2 + 200);
    };
};
```

The "subtitle" renders fine.   But the "splashImage" does not.   I see that the image is successfully loaded by looking at the Network tab in Chrome.   So it appears that the image is found but never renders.

Any ideas on where my syntax is wrong?

---

**UPDATE:** Must be something in the rest of the code ...

If I change:

```
splashImage.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(splashImage, Game.width / 2 - 420 / 2, Game.height / 2 - 100, 420, 263);
        }
```

to

```
ctx.drawImage(splashImage, Game.width / 2 - 420 / 2, Game.height / 2 - 100, 420, 263);
```

it works a-okay!  Odd...

Comment: Your syntax is fine otherwise you would see a syntax error and none of your code would run. In fact, [it seems to work for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/wjrwtowj/1/) Could you please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help?

Comment: Could you add a console log inside image onload function?
Seems to work for me as well.

Comment: See update above.   Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: You're creating a global variable with `splashImage`. It should be `var splashImage = new Image()`. Perhaps that's what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If adding the width and height parameters fixed the problem, it could be that your image does not have the size you expected, or perhaps it does not even have an intrinsic size, as is sometimes the case with SVG files.  If that is not what is going on, it could be a bug in the browser.  Please file a bug if that is the case.  You can submit bugs against Chrome here: [crbug.com/newissue](http://crbug.com/newissue)

Comment: it wasn't the width and height change that made it work, it was removing the surrounding splashImage.onLoad

Comment: without the onload, your page will be flaky. Your image will only be immediately available if it is in the browser's cache. If a network transfer is necessary for downloading the image, using on load is essential. Is your 'ctx' drawing directly into a canvas that is on the page or is it just an intermediate.  If it is an intermediate that gets extracted (drawImage into another canvas, toDataURL, upload to WebGL texture), then you need to make sure the extraction happens after splahImage.onload has been called, otherwise you will be capturing the canvas contents before the call to drawImage